# Use BCTabBarController in iPhone Project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add **BCTabbarController** project in my iPhone project.

Step which I followed:

1. Drag `BCTabbarcontroller.xcodeproject` in my existing project.
2. Add Target Dependency of `BCTabarcontroller`.
3. Add `BCTabBarcontroller.bundle` in my project.

**Issue**
I want to use the `BCTabbarcontroller` in `AppDeleagte` file but it does not work.

Any pointers on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by _"it does not work"_? Do you get any build errors?

Comment: @Amar its eroe like 'BCTabBarController.h' file not found
#import "BCTabBarController.h"

Comment: Did you follow the steps correctly given on the [github page of the project](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController#usage)?

Comment: @Amar yes i am using that stp but still not work for me :)

Comment: Going to my project/target/Build Phases/Target Dependencies and adding BCTabbarController (little house icon) its appear as red

Comment: Check out my answer. I have tried these steps and it worked for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36068/discussion-between-rushabh-and-amar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps that worked for me.

- Copy entire `BCTabBarController` folder into your project.
- Add `BCTabBarController.xcodeproj` to your project by dragging it into the Groups & Files sidebar.
- Goto your project target->Build Phases and add Target Dependency for `BCTabBarController` static library.
- Also, under Link Binary with Libraries->add `libBCTabBarController.a`. Screenshot for above two steps is as below.

[image]

- Drag BCTabBarController.bundle into your project's resources.
- Under project target->Build Settings->Header Search paths add `${SRCROOT}/BCTabBarController/src/**`

[image]

- In `AppDelegate` import the header and use the controller.

  ```
  #import "BCTabBarController/src/BCTabBarController.h"
  ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank You, Its working for me. As I forgot to set the Header Search Paths.

Comment: +1 working like charm thanks for help :)